# Juint parallel execution

Tags: ant, junit, parallel-processing

I have one question regarding junit parallel test execution.what happens when I am putting my test suit in parallel tag of ant file?Reason I am asking this,I am running a test case on two devices(ios+android).Some times this test class is passing in one ios and during second or third run it is passing for second device and vice versa.What should i do in this case,from my understanding some issue is with threading.Is this issue I have to handle with some synchronized block Could any let me know as what could be the issue as I am confused here.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was related with the framework we developed.We developed in such a way that only single object will be created.Now after removing all static keyword from methods and variables my tests are getting executed in parallel.
So,if you want your test scripts to run in parallel don't make everything static.